# Unable to start tomcat9 on SSL mode with spring boot 2 and trust store

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

Getting below error while using both trust store and key store but without trust store (with only key store), it is working fine.

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.anz.cis.lwc.LwcMediationServiceV1Application.main(LwcMediationServiceV1Application.java:20) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:224) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:550) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:957) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:157) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:130) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getParameters(JSSEUtil.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getTrustManagers(JSSEUtil.java:314) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:224) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:550) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:957) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
```

Comment: If i am using only trust store then getting below error:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLHostConfig attribute certificateFile must be defined when using an SSL connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks most likely that your trust store file does not contain any X509 certificates. If you take a look at the code for `java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>` from your stack trace you'll see this:

```
    Set<TrustAnchor> hashSet = new HashSet<TrustAnchor>();
    Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        if (keystore.isCertificateEntry(alias)) {
            Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            if (cert instanceof X509Certificate)
                hashSet.add(new TrustAnchor((X509Certificate)cert, null));
        }
    }
    setTrustAnchors(hashSet);
```

That seems to suggest that either your file doesn't contain any certs, or the ones that it does contain are not `X509Certificate` instances.

You can check the contents of your file using:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

You might also want to check out the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) which provides detailed instructions on how to create those files.

Comment: Think you Phil , I have checked with above key-tool command and found there exist certificate :
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: tq-bfdd1bc2-e9ce-4356-8e12-daef2a6c66c5
Creation date: Apr 17, 2020
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:

*Note: its having chain of trust (3 level)**

Comment: One certificate was missing on jks file. After imported it's working fine.